# Cannot convert value of type 'String?' (Alamofire)

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I map my class User with object mapper:

```
class User: Mappable{

private var _username: String! = nil
private var _password: String! = nil
private var _firstName: String! = nil
private var _lastName: String! = nil

//here are getters and setters(it takes too much space)

init(){

}

required init?(_ map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    username <- map["USERNAME"]
    password <- map["PASSWORD"]
    firstName <- map["FIRST_NAME"]
    lastName <- map["LAST_NAME"]

  }
}
```

And then i tried to make new user and put some values, map the whole object and send with Alamofire like this:

```
let userEmail = userEmailField.text!
let userPassword = userPasswordField.text!

let user = User()
user.username = userEmail
user.password = userPassword
let JSONString = Mapper().toJSONString(user, prettyPrint: true)

AlamofireService.alamofireService.makePostServiceRequest(URL_BASE, parameters: JSONString, resposeCallback: self)
```

I followed the instructions of libraries, but i get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'", why?

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: @MatanLachmish sorry i forgot to write. I edit my question.

Comment: What is the sense of using private instance variables with getters and setters? This is Swift! And what is the sense of implicit unwrapped optionals in an init method? Either the values can be `nil` then declare them as **real** optional or if they are never `nil` declare them as non-optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alamofire request taking parameter in [String: AnyObject] format so you just need to pass dictionary as parameter. in your case you just need like:

```
let userEmail = userEmailField.text!
let userPassword = userPasswordField.text!

var dictParameter: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [:]
dictParameter["USERNAME"]   = userEmail
dictParameter["PASSWORD"]   = userPassword
```

And after that Just make request:

```
AlamofireService.alamofireService.makePostServiceRequest(URL_BASE, parameters: dictParameter, resposeCallback: self)
```

Comment: And the best way to deal with response is Alamofire Object mapper, right?

Comment: And what if i have to send an object? because there is too many informations that i have to send, and it would be too complicated to type as dictionary?

Comment: nice answer bro. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to covert your parameters to string, just pass parameters as dictionary to Alamofire.